# Question about exponential function construction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Reading [Rudin](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf)(pg. 22) the question 6 is about exponential function construction.

> 6. Fix $b>1.$
>
> (a) If $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n>0,q>0,$ and $r=m/n=p/q,$ prove that $$(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}.$$ Hence it makes sense to define $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}.$
>
> (b) Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational.
>
> (c) If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t,$ where $t$ is rational and $t\le x.$ Prove that $$b^r= \sup B(r)$$ when $r$ is rational. Hence it makes sense to define $b^x=\sup B(x)$ for every real $x.$

My question is how can i prove item c) and more important Why does it make sense to define $B(x)$? It goes straight from rational to real, so that already takes the irrational, right? and it makes sense for example $2^{\pi}$, or any irrational exponent. Any help with the construction, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are updating the definition of $b^x$ ($b>1$ fixed).

- Originally, $b^x$ is defined for nonnegative integers $x=n\in\mathbb{N}$:
  $$
  b^n:=\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdots b}_{n \textrm{ factors}}
  $$
  where we use the convention that $b^0=1$.
- We also define for *positive* integer $n$, 
  $$
  b^{-n}:=\frac{1}{b^n}.
  $$
- By existence of $\sqrt[n]{b}$ for positive integer $n$, (see Rundin), we are allowed to define
  $$
  b^{1/n}:=\sqrt[n]{b},\quad,n=1,2,3,\cdots
  $$
- Then by Problem 6(a) in Rudin, we can define
  $$
  b^r:=(b^m)^{1/n},\quad r=\frac{m}{n},\quad m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}.
  $$

  For $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, observes from Problem b(c) that
  $$
  b^r=\sup B(r) \tag{1}
  $$
  where the set $B(r):=\{b^t\mid t\le r,t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.
- Now for general $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we *define* 
  $$
  b^x:=\sup B(x) \tag{2}
  $$
  where the set $B(x):=\{b^t\mid t\le x,t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. 
  This definition *makes sense* because (1) is true. It would *not* make sense **if** (1) is not true, because $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and by (2) means (1) must be true.

---

To prove (1), i.e., the statement in Problem (c), simply follow the definition and show the following:

- show $b^r\leq \sup B(r)$ by observing that $b^r\in B(r)$;
- show that $b^r\geq \sup B(r)$ by observing that $b^r\geq b^t$ for any $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $t\leq r$.

Comment: a last question, What would happen if $0<b<1$ or $b<0 ?, thanks for explanation

Comment: Since $b^x$ has been defined for $b>1$ and *any* $x\in\mathbb{R}$, when $b\in(0,1)$, one can defined $b^x:=(\frac{1}{b})^{-x}$. In real analysis, one does not consider functions $x\mapsto b^x$ for $b<0$. See also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases). But in complex analysis, one can define such function by complex logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the definition of $B(x)$? There were irrational numbers in this context before its introduction; for instance, $2^{1/2}$ is irrational.

The set $B(x)$ is defined as the set of all *real* numbers of the form $b^t$, where $t$ is *rational* and $t\leqslant x$. It is a set of real numbers, which has an upper bound. And then Rudin defines $b^x$ as $\sup B(x)$. There is no problem here (except that one needs to prove that the set $B(x)$ has un upper bound).

Comment: Yes, i want to know item c) and why make sense that definition for $x$ real also, maybe it's obvious but i dont understand

Comment: *What* is that you don't understand?

Comment: why make sense that definition for x real

Comment: Since $B(x)$ is non-empty and has un upper bound, $\sup B(x)$ exists. Therefore, it makes sense to define something as $\sup B(x)$.

Comment: $x$ is a real number. $B(x)$ is a $\textit{set}$. Its members are all $b^r$ for rational $r\le x$. Now define $b^x$ to be the sup of this set. There are some things to check but the definitions are clear, aren't they?